# Data Deletion in File Using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

As new programmer in Python Programming Language, I thought to create a student Database Management System in Python. But while deleting the Data from the file I got stuck and I thought to apply these steps to the file to delete the characters but how shall I Implement it? I have developed my code but it's not working.

The algorithm:

STEP 1: Create an additional file and open the current file in reading mode and open the new file in writing mode

STEP 2: Read and copy the Data to the newly created file except for the line we want to delete

STEP 3: Close both the file and remove the old file and rename the newly created file with the deleted filename

But while implementing it I got stuck on how to implement as it is not remaining the same.

Here is the code which I wrote:

```
def delete():
    rollno = int(input('\n Enter The Roll number : '))
    f = open('BCAstudents3.txt','r')
    f1 = open('temp.txt','a+')
    for line in f:
        fo = line.split()
        if fo:
            if fo[3] != rollno:
                f1.write(str(str(fo).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace("'","").replace(",","")))
    f.close()
    f1.close()
    os.remove('BCAstudents3.txt')
    os.rename('temp.txt','BCAstudents3.txt')
```

The Data From the Original File Looks Like This :

```
Roll Number = 1 Name : Alex Section = C Optimisation Technique = 99 Maths III = 99 Operating System = 99 Software Engneering = 99 Computer Graphics = 99 {Here Line change is present but it is not showing while typing on to stackoverflow } Roll Number = 2 Name : Shay Section = C Optimisation Technique = 99 Maths III = 99 Operating System = 99 Software Engneering = 99 Computer Graphics = 99`
```

and the Resullt after The Deletion is this :

```
Roll Number = 1 Name : Alex Section = C Optimisation Technique = 99 Maths III = 99 Operating System = 99 Software Engneering = 99 Computer Graphics = 99Roll Number = 2 Name : Shay Section = C Optimisation Technique = 99 Maths III = 99 Operating System = 99 Software Engneering = 99 Computer Graphics = 99
```

and I also want to give comma after the end of the data But don't have any idea that how to do this one

Comment: Curently your post shows input and output as a single long line. Is that actually the case?

Comment: So the idea is that the user enters a roll number N and you remove line N from the text file? Or do you remove the line from the text file that contains "Roll Number = N"? Presume the latter.

Comment: yes it shows the single long line as the output

Comment: I want to remove the "Roll Number =  N" from the text file

Comment: It's unclear how you want this design to work.  You read the file by lines, but your data is contained in one line.  Your supposed input has what appears to be an embedded comment.  You say you don't know how to insert a comma, although this is a common desire that is covered in many tutorials on string usage and CSV files.  As best I can tell, the current blocking point is that you need a little more work in file tutorials.  Also consider reading the entire file into some appropriate data structure (dict, list, or data frame) where it's easier to search for data.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code and it should work how you wanted. A couple of things to consider:

1. Your original text file seems to indicate that there are line breaks for each Roll Number. I assumed that with my answer.
2. Because you are reading a text file, there are no integers so fo[3] would not ever match rollno if you are converting the input to an int.
3. I wasn't sure exactly where you wanted the comma. After each line? Or just at the very end.

I wasn't sure if you wanted new lines for each Roll Number.

```
def delete():
    rollno = input('\n Enter The Roll number : ')
    f = open('BCAstudents3.txt','r')
    f1 = open('temp.txt','a+')
    for line in f:
        fo = line.split()
        if fo:
            if fo[3] != rollno:
                newline = " ".join(fo) + ","
                #print(newline)
                f1.write(newline)

    f.close()
    f1.close()
    os.remove('BCAstudents3.txt')
    os.rename('temp.txt','BCAstudents3.txt')
```

Answer (score 1):

I made your programm a little simpler.
Hopefully you can use it:

```
def delete():   
    line = input("Line you want to delete: ")
    line = int(line)                    
    line -= 1                           
     
    file = open("file.txt","r")
    data = file.readlines()        
    del data[line]

    file = open("file.txt","w") 
    for line in data:
        file.write(line)

    file.close()
```